# "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" upon adding OR parameter

Tags: php, sql

Below is a function I am trying to run via PHP, if I remove the section "H=Y OR ?" and instead just run it as "H=?" it runs perfectly fine. Any help figuring out why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getInfo($Z)
{
   global $mysqli;

   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,I,J FROM DB WHERE H=Y OR ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $Z);
   $stmt->execute();

   $stmt->bind_result($A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F,$G,$I,$J);

   while ($stmt->fetch())
   {
      echo "$A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F,$G,$I,$J\n";
   }

   $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: Because that's not valid SQL.  It needs to be `H=Y OR H=?`, or `H IN (Y, ?)`

Comment: This means that `mysqli->prepare()` got an error and returned `false` instead of a statement. You need to print `$mysqli->error` to see the reason.

Comment: I tried changing it to both "(H=Y) OR (H=?)" AND "H IN (Y,?)" to no avail. Any other ideas as to why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for it to be H=Y or H=? like this:

```
... FROM DB WHERE (H=Y) OR (H=?)
```

Comment: I tried changing it to both "(H=Y) OR (H=?)" AND "H IN (Y,?)" to no avail. Any other ideas as to why it isn't working?